# Input and output pipe in Lazarus TProcess

Tags: process, lazarus

I would like to make a terminal with a Lazarus GUI application. But I'm in trouble. And I hope someone can help me, please.

*Question1*: The Chinese and other special chars cannot display normally, I would like to know how to fix this problem.
[(code)Class of the thread and "run" button on click event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZObEW.png)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pymqT.png)

*Question2*: I want to know how to input some command into the console. I tried to start a Windows cmd, and use "winver" command. But when I click the button, nothing happened.

[The send command button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfZfC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winver is not console but a GUI program.  To run a program with output into memo, use the following code, which retrieves version using the cmd.exe "ver" command. You can try to use this template for the first question too.

```pascal
    unit mainprocesstomemo;
    
    {$mode delphi}{$H+}
    
    interface
    
    uses
      Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, Process, Pipes;
    
    Type
      { TForm1 }
    
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        Memo1: TMemo;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
      public
        procedure ProcessEvent(Sender,Context : TObject;Status:TRunCommandEventCode;const Message:string);
      end;
    
    var
      Form1: TForm1;
    
    implementation
    
    {$R *.lfm}
    
    { TProcessMemo }
    Type
    
     TProcessToMemo = class(TProcess)
                                public
                                fmemo : Tmemo;
                                bytesprocessed : integer;
                                fstringsadded : integer;
                                function ReadInputStream(p:TInputPipeStream;var BytesRead:integer;var DataLength:integer;var Data:string;MaxLoops:integer=10):boolean;override;
                              end;
    
    
    
    function RunCommandMemo(const exename:TProcessString;const commands:array of TProcessString;out outputstring:string; Options : TProcessOptions = [];SWOptions:TShowWindowOptions=swoNone;memo:TMemo=nil;runrefresh : TOnRunCommandEvent=nil ):boolean;
    Var
        p : TProcessToMemo;
        i,
        exitstatus : integer;
        ErrorString : String;
    begin
      p:=TProcessToMemo.create(nil);
      if Options<>[] then
        P.Options:=Options - [poRunSuspended,poWaitOnExit];
      p.options:=p.options+[poRunIdle];
    
      P.ShowWindow:=SwOptions;
      p.Executable:=exename;
      if high(commands)>=0 then
       for i:=low(commands) to high(commands) do
         p.Parameters.add(commands[i]);
      p.fmemo:=memo;
      p.OnRunCommandEvent:=runrefresh;
      try
        result:=p.RunCommandLoop(outputstring,errorstring,exitstatus)=0;
      finally
        p.free;
      end;
      if exitstatus<>0 then result:=false;
    end;
    
    { TForm1 }
    
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var s : string;
    begin
    //RunCommandMemo('testit',[],s,[],swonone,memo1,ProcessEvent);
      RunCommandMemo('cmd.exe',['/w','/c','ver'],s,[],swonone,memo1,ProcessEvent);
    end;
    
    procedure TForm1.ProcessEvent(Sender, Context: TObject;
      Status: TRunCommandEventCode; const Message: string);
    begin
      if status in [RunCommandIdle, RunCommandFinished] then
        begin
          if status =RunCommandFinished then
            begin
              memo1.lines.add(' process finished');
            end;
          if tprocesstomemo(sender).fstringsadded>0 then
           begin
             tprocesstomemo(sender).fstringsadded:=0;
    //         memo1.lines.add('Handle:'+inttostr(tprocesstomemo(sender).ProcessHandle));
             memo1.refresh;
           end;
          sleep(10);
          application.ProcessMessages;
        end;
    end;
    
    { TProcessToMemo }
    
    
    function TProcessToMemo.ReadInputStream(p:TInputPipeStream;var BytesRead:integer;var DataLength:integer;var Data:string;MaxLoops:integer=10):boolean;
    var lfpos : integer;
        crcorrectedpos:integer;
        stradded : integer;
        newstr : string;
    begin
      Result:=inherited ReadInputStream(p, BytesRead, DataLength, data, MaxLoops);
      if (result) and (bytesread>bytesprocessed)then
        begin
          stradded:=0;
          lfpos:=pos(#10,data,bytesprocessed+1);
          while (lfpos<>0) and (lfpos<=bytesread) do
            begin
              crcorrectedpos:=lfpos;
              if (crcorrectedpos>0) and (data[crcorrectedpos-1]=#13) then
                 dec(crcorrectedpos);
              newstr:=copy(data,bytesprocessed+1,crcorrectedpos-bytesprocessed-1);
              fmemo.lines.add(newstr);
               inc(stradded);
              bytesprocessed:=lfpos;
              lfpos:=pos(#10,data,bytesprocessed+1);
            end;
          inc(fstringsadded,stradded); // check idle event.
        end;
    end;
    
    end.
```

I don't know minecraft server, and many external programs might do weird things to the console. But a simple combination of programs to test with is here [http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/files/processmemodemo.zip](http://www.stack.nl/%7Emarcov/files/processmemodemo.zip)

Comment: Thanks. And how can I input a command after starting the program? For **example**, I would like to start a Minecraft server, and execute a command in the console with TProcess.

Comment: See last paragraph